# Does $\{A_k,A_k^*\}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ imply $\{A_k^\prime,A_k^{\prime*}\}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$? Here, $A_k^\prime:=S^{-1}A_kS$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_k\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a family of matrices and denote by $\{A_k,A_k^*\}$ the algebra generated by $A_k$ and their conjugate transpose. Suppose that $S$ is a positive matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Define $A_k^\prime:=S^{-1}A_kS$. Does $\{A_k,A_k^*\}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ imply $\{A_k^\prime,A_k^{\prime*}\}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Are you sure? Suppose $p(A_k^{\prime},A_k^{\prime*})=A_k^\prime+A_k^{\prime*}$. Then $p(A_k^{\prime},A_k^{\prime*})=S^{-1}A_kS+SA_k^*S^{-1}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought you were conjugating every element in the same way.